# PUT request is not working in node.js when fetching some id from Url

Tags: node.js

i am testing this url==> (http://localhost:8800/api/users/634ed4af41fb0169e999deb2/follow) on
postman, it works in case of without having (/follow), But when i use this url every time i get this error=====>

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot PUT /api/users/634ed4af41fb0169e999deb2/follow%0A</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Below i am getting issue in using // app.use('/api/users',userRoutes)//. This will call the router present in the users.js

**index.js**

```
const express= require("express");
const app=express();
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const dotenv=require("dotenv");
const helmet=require("helmet");
const morgan=require("morgan");
const userRoutes=require("./routes/users")
const authRoutes=require("./routes/auth");


dotenv.config();
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, 
    {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, ()=>{
    console.log("connected to database");
});

//middleware

app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("common"));


//cutom middleware for Routing

app.use('/api/users',userRoutes);
app.use('/api/auth',authRoutes);

app.listen(8800,()=>{
    console.log("backend server running");
})
```

here in user.js controller are not able to log the console present at the top position.

**user.js**

```
 const router=require("express").Router();
    const bcrypt=require('bcrypt');
    const User = require("../models/User");
    
      //follow user
        


router.put("/:id/follow", async (req , res)=>{
  console.log(req.body.userId === req.params.id.trim());
    if(req.body.userId !== req.params.id){
        try {
           const user= await User.findById(req.params.id);
      const currentUser= await User.findById(req.body.userId);
   if(!user.followers.includes(req.body.userId)){
   await user.updateOne({$push:{followers:req.body.userId}});
                            
   await currentUser.updateOne({$push:{followings:req.params.id}});
       res.status(200).json("user has been follwed")
   }else{
    res.status(403).json('you all ready followed')
       }
   } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json(error)
       }
      }
      else{
    res.status(403).json("you cant follow yourself")
       }
     })
```

Comment: What if you remove that `%0A` from the requested URL?

Comment: As you can see in the URL in the error, there is a trailing `%0A`, i.e. a newline character. Remove that newline (for example using `.trim()`) before stuffing the value into the URL. (Or perhaps fix the place where you get this from so it won't even return the newline in the first place.)

Comment: @CherryDT can you please show me how to remove that newline before stuffing the value into the URL, because i just pasting that id from mongodb

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros i can't remove that ,because that is coming from error.

Comment: "can you please show me how to remove that newline" << using [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) - "i can't remove that ,because that is coming from error." << No, it's coming from elsewhere in your code, as it's at the end of the URL that you call! The error is wherever you build that URL. (You didn't show the code that builds the URL so I can't tell where exactly.)

Comment: @CherryDT yes i got that place on the URL which giving extra space that was causing problem. Thanks for guidance